# What does REL mean on installing VS 2013?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

When I installed Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate, it gave me version "Visual Studio 2013 (12.0.21005.1 REL)".

What is meaning of REL?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm pretty sure "REL" means "Release".

Comment: is it?? It that this simple??

Comment: Yup! It's that simple. Why?